# ObservableCollection Images in Listbox to Content Control master detail WPf

Tags: wpf, observablecollection

I have an observablecollection of Images that get populated via the following code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0">
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding BigImageView}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
           SelectedIndex="0" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}" />
</StackPanel>
<ContentControl Name="Detail" Content="{Binding BigImageView, Mode=OneWay}"
                Margin="9,0,0,0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

However the Content Control is supposed to bind to the BigImageView via an ObservableCollection

```
 BigImage = new ObservableCollection<Image>();

 _listView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(BigImage);
 _listView.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(OnCurrentChanged);

 public System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView BigImageView
 {
   get
   {
     return _listView;
   }
   set
   {
     _listView = value;
     OnPropertyChanged("BigImageView");
   }
 }
```

I want to return the image to the content control when I move the listbox. I have been racking my brain and trying everyhitn but it does not work. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to bind the selecteditem, the collectionview should take care of that.

Try this:

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding BigImageView}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />

 <ContentControl Name="Detail" Content="{Binding BigImageView, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top">

    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: I get a SYSTEM.WINDOWS.DATA.LISTVIEWCOLLECTION in place withere the content control is. I have to imagine that this has been solved in the past but I'm too new at WPF.

Comment: You need to specify a template for the content control. I edited my answer.

Comment: Erno, In my viewmodel I have other buttons and other business logic inside of it. When I do the Binding nothing shows. I tried making a converter: Image -> Image Source but still doesn't work. Do you know what the correct way is to show an Image? Perhaps I should try and make a tree, similar to the Photo Viewer that Microsoft provides and do that that way instead of a master detail model. Your thoughts?

Comment: @Axwack, Your viewmodel has buttons?! Do you see any binding errors in the output? Can you post a minimal example of what you are doing so we can reproduce?

Answer (score 0):

## 1

Create a viewmodel with a list and a selected item:

```
public class BigImageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
     private string bigImage;

     //string for path? 
     public ObservableCollection<string> BigImageView {get; set; } //Of course, make sure it has a value

     public string SelectedBigImage          
     {
         get { return bigImage; } 
         set { bigImage = values; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedBigImage"); }
     }
}
```

Set this object on the DataContext of your control in the constructor:

```
DataContext = new BigImage(); //Make sure you initialize your list
```

Set the ListBox ItemsSource to your BigImage list, bind your SelectedItem to BigImageView
 and use that in your content control:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding BigImageView}" SelectedItem={Binding SelectedBigImage} />
```

ContentControl:

```
<ContentControl Name="Detail" Content="{Binding SelectedBigImage, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top">

   <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Image Source="{Binding}"/> <!-- Nice template for showing your string BigImage -->
       </DataTemplate>
   <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

---

## 2

Or screw that view model:

Set the list directly in the constructor (after the InitializeComponent() ):

```
myListBox.ItemsSource = ObservableCollection<string>(); //Make sure you initialize your list with whatever your object is..
```

Give the list a name:

And bind with an ElementName binding to your selected item:

```
<ContentControl Name="Detail" Content="{Binding ElementName=myListBox, Path=SelectedItem}" VerticalAlignment="Top">

   <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Image Source="{Binding}"/> <!-- Nice template for showing your string BigImage -->
       </DataTemplate>
   <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: I've assumed you will use string.. But you can also use ImageSource, or any other object your want. Just be aware, that when you use WPF controls in your ObservableCollection, it will only render itself once.. not twice..

Comment: Hi Arcturus, your code is very good. Just wanted to say that the class is the following: public class Page1ViewModel : PageViewModelBase which inherits : INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Alright.. then my BigImageViewModel is your Page1ViewModel ;)

Comment: Thanks Arcturus but since I have this already in the viewmodel...why would I do this again? I'm just not following.

Comment: You shouldnt.. just make sure your Page1ViewModel is set on your DataContext and follow my instructions above..